# Token(CannotCreate) error on transferring asset to PalletId account

Tags: error, assets, palletid

I'm new to Substrate and I'm creating a pallet in which the user can create contests by depositing a certain amount of assets. My idea is to send that amount to the PalletId account, but I'm having an error "Err(Token(CannotCreate))" when testing, and it's happening in the following function:

```
T::Assets::transfer(
  prize_token_id,
  &who,
  &Self::account_id(),
  prize_token_amount,
  false
)?;
```

I didn't find it when I tried to see if anyone had something like this. I know the error is related to providers and consumers, but I couldn't relate it to my problem.

What could be happening to throw this error?

EDITED:

The repo is here: https://github.com/pablolteixeira/constests-unit-network/blob/main/substrate-node-unitchain/pallets/contests/src/lib.rs

On line 240, it's possible to find the "transfer" function that is panicking.

`cargo test -p pallet-contests` is sufficient to see the error happening.

Comment: Need more context. Which pallets are you using? Please include the repo for your code. Ideally also include steps to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, this could be your issue:

The [tokens trait](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/index.html) has an [DepositConsequence](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/enum.DepositConsequence.html) enum which one of its variants is [CannotCreate](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/enum.DepositConsequence.html#variant.CannotCreate) which means:

> Deposit cannot happen since the account cannot be created (usually because it’s a consumer and there exists no provider reference).

Answer (score 1):

Check if your pallet account has enough native balance. If it has less than existential balance this error can occur